# I don't have an account on Flickr. Why am I shown as logged into Flickr on a fingerprinting website?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, fingerprinting

If I visit https://browserleaks.com/social using the Tor Browser, I am shown as somehow logged into Flickr. I don't even have a Flickr account.

In addition to the above, visiting the same site on a Google Chrome browser on the same computer shows me the exact same thing - logged into Flickr.

What could be the cause of this? Grateful for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like their script is broken.

It's trying to detect if you're signed in by checking if the login page redirects you to a favicon.ico file and flickr.com is redirecting anyway.

```
...
    }, {
        domain: "https://www.flickr.com",
        redirect: "/signin/yahoo/?redir=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com/favicon.ico",
        name: "Flickr"
    }, {
...
```

If you visit `https://www.flickr.com/signin/yahoo/?redir=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com/favicon.ico` it will redirect you to `/favicon.ico`

So their website is failing to detect it correctly.

Comment: Yes, testing this out further seems to suggest that the issue is indeed what you suggest. Thanks.